# dynamic directive compile passing the right scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have dynamic directive which compiles any given directive, the problem is on compile function i need to provide a right scope to it, Jus thinking how to do this?

example of my directive below, 'directive' scope input is dynamic, for example it could be `<display-users data="users"/>` the user are part of the controller which loads this directive.

Although below compilation works correctly, the since it is not asscociating compilred code with the right scope (in the above case controller one) it does not diplay the users. Please can someone help?

```
theApp.directive('customCompile',
   function ($compile) 
   {
      var dir = 
      {
           replace: true, // replace the original html ? required for restrict = "M" 
           restrict: 'E', //can be one or more of E / A / C / M
           scope:{
             directive:'='
           },
           controller: function ($scope, $http, $attrs) // The controller for the directive
           {

           },
            compile: function compile($element, $tAttrs, $transclude) {
              return{
                 post: function postLink($scope, $iElement, $iAttrs){

                    $iElement.parent().append($compile($scope.directive.directive)($scope));    

                 }
              }

            }
       };

       return dir;
    }
);
```

Comment: Have you tried `$iElement.scope()`? Can you provide a plunker or jsfiddle example?

Comment: $iElement.scope() does not work, creating jsfiddle example one sec

Comment: ok got it working, dynamic directive post link compile needs a correct scope to be attached to it